# SQL Server service is stopping, occasionally, and neither SQL Server Log nor Event Log contains a clue as to why

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

We are experiencing a situation I've never seen before.  3 times over the past week (once during the day and twice in the evening), the SQL Server service has stopped - and checking the Windows Event Log and SQL Server logs has yet to yield any messages that suggest what caused the stoppage.

There isn't a notification that the SQL Server service has entered the stopped state, or any suspicious error messages around the time that the database stopped responding.

Are there any other good places to look for clues? Anyone else encounter this sort of behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: You state at the end "the database stopped responding"  - did the service ***actually*** stop or was it just unresponsive?  Do you get a new error log and the startup messages in the log?  If not then you need to try and identify what was using all the resources - which then could be many things including storage, networking, server memory etc etc

Comment: I've experienced similar and found it very frustrating and tricky to get to the bottom of. I'm pretty sure in our case it relates to poor disk subsystem performance - but it's on a shared SAN with nearly all the organisation's activity on it, hosted by an external supplier. Add to that a complex virtual infrastructure and overstretched IT department, tying to get details of the issue or any kind of metrics is like pulling teeth... any permanent solution feels like a pipe dream. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would check the cluster log for anything.

Also if you know the time the SQL stopped, you could use Powershell to search though every event log 1 minute before the error happened and read them all you might find something this way. Check the Windows logs and application and service.